Whether $\text{TQBF}\in\mathbf{PH}$ by a set theory inference
Let $L_i\subseteq\text{TQBF}$ be the set of true $i$-run PNF quantified boolean formulas, e.g. $\exists x\;\forall y\;\exists z\;((x\land z)\lor y)\in L_3$. As a result, we have $\text{TQBF}=\bigcup_{i\ge 0} L_i$.
IMO, $L_i\in\Sigma_i^p$, so $L_i\in\mathbf{PH}$. Consequently, $\text{TQBF}\in\mathbf{PH}$ because each $L_i\in\mathbf{PH}$. What is a set theory inference pointing out that the statement is wrong? I worry about the infinite union may not be treated as finite union.
From my point of view, it is not true because each $L\in\mathbf{PH}$ should get a fixed numbers, say, $k$ polynomial-time verifiable certificates. We need to prove that $\text{TQBF}$ needs only some $k$ certificates to solve.

(I assume you mean the set of true i-run PNF quantified boolean formulas.) Just because each $L_i$ is in PH doesn't mean their union is. A decider for TBQF single algorithm that works for any number of quantifiers.

I think your last paragraph is the right idea. (And also, yes, there’s a distinction to be drawn between finite and infinite union.) Note also that TBQF would be a complete problem for PH, so would collapse the hierarchy to whatever level it happened to be on.

@spaceisdarkgreen Could you explain the difference between finite and infinite union in this case?

If you've heard "PH is closed under unions", that just means it is closed under finite unions. The argument only works for finite unions... you can e.g. show that if $L_1,L_2\in \sf PH$ then $L_1\cup L_2\in \sf PH$ and then by induction that extends to finite unions. But that doesn't imply it's closed under countably infinite unions. As a simple counterexample, the collection of finite sets of natural numbers is closed under finite unions, but not infinite unions.

@spaceisdarkgreen Oh, I see. That's so great.

To bring it to the extreme, every language is a countable union of one-element languages, which have trivial complexity. Thus by this logic, $\mathbf{ALL=P}$, or even $\mathbf{ALL=L}$.

@EmilJeřábek I have realized that we shouldn't treat infinite union as finite union, but rather try another way such as the last paragraph if we are not master at it.

@minhquýlê Just to be clear about the last paragraph, I was saying you were right about why the demonstration that TBQF is in PH is incorrect and what you would  actually have to do, in theory, to show it. I wasn’t saying it was a promising approach… it is believed that TBQF is not in PH (as I mentioned, it would collapse the PH if it were), though of course there’s no proof of that.
